# how to overcome 120 sec timeout in JS remoting

Tags: javascript-remoting, timeout

i did try below solution,

```
Visualforce.remoting.timeout = 120000;
```

I am still getting the timeout issue. The remote method is hardly 40 lines code and is optimized also i am not making callouts in the method.

Please guide on how to overcome this issue.

Comment: You can't. You have a two minute limit, and that's it. I can hardly imagine any Apex Code that runs in 2 minutes without hitting governor limits, though. You may need to break your work into multiple parts, or look for other optimizations you could do.

Comment: Thanks for replying @sfdcfox. Can i write multiple remote methods which i call one after the other. Will it solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, you can call the second in response to the receipt of the data from the first.

Comment: If you [edit] your post to include your code, we may be better able to assist you.